# Hidden button from other view controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I try to hide two button in 1st view controller from 2nd view controller. While i am try to call function from 2nd view controller to 1st, control is passing correctly i have check by break point, but the action is not has been done.my code on 1st view controller

```
-(void)action
{
    if(btnAddFriends.hidden==YES)
    {
        btnAddFriends.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        btnAddFriends.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

2nd view controller

```
1stview *jsq = [[1stview alloc] init];
[jsq action];
```

Comment: you are doing it in the wrong way. you are creating a new instance of `1stview`. you have to call the action on existing instance of `1stview`.

Comment: can you explain clearly

Comment: you can achieve this in several ways, can you show the code of how you are showing 2nv VC from 1st view controller?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are creating a new controller (the alloc/init sequence...) not using the already existing one: this also explain why you can debug it even if it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are create new object for 1st view controller .
this methods not called for previous viewController because that viewController's Object is different Thats why your methods doesn't call 
i hope You understand 
and it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference your existing 1stview instead of creating another new one if you want to call the method of 1stview from the 2ndview.

The code would be more or less like this:

1.- Create a property in 2ndview.h:

`@property(nonatomic, strong) 1stviewClass* 1stview;`

2.- In 1stview, assign self to the property created in step 1:

`2ndview.1stview = self;`

3.- In 2ndview call the method you need from 1stview:

`[1stview hideButtons];`

You can also create a protocol to send a message from 2ndview to 1stview.